# Randomize different ArrayList to get a value

Tags: android, list, random, arraylist

I searched for related questions but didn´t find a solution (at least i don´t know if i named it correctly)

So, i have two ArrayLists and i would like to randomize all of them to get a value:

```
public class ListBox {

public static ArrayList listOne(){


    ArrayList<Lists> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
    listOne.add(new Item("Text One"));
    listOne.add(new Item("Text Two"));
    return listOne;

}

   public static ArrayList listTwo(){


    ArrayList<Lists> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    listTwo.add(new Item("Text Three"));
    listTwo.add(new Item("Text Four"));
    return listTwo;

}
 }
```

in other activity:

```
   public void buttonClick(View view){

  ArrayList<Lists> algumasListas = ListBox.listOne();
...

 }
```

This is where i shuffle it

```
 public class ListMixer extends ListBox{
  public ArrayList<Lists> listas = null;

  public ListMixer(ArrayList<Lists> listas ) {
    this.listas = listas;
  }

  protected String mixList(){
    Double randomNumber = new Double(Math.random() * listas.size());

    int randomNum = randomNumber.intValue();
    Lista lista= listas.get(randomNum);

    String listaString2 = String.valueOf(lista);

  String message = ("This is your list: " + listas);

  return message;



}


}
```

my desired output would be one of the four listItems.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Add the sizes of L1.Size + L2.Size (gives N), pick a random number between [0,N-1] (call it K), if K < L1.Size, pick it from L1 (`L1[K]`). If K >= L1, pick K - L1.Size from L2 (`L2[K - L1.Size]`. No need to create a new array since that would be very costly

Answer (score 0):

1. Merge arrays into single one of size N.
2. Choose a random number in range 0..N-1.
3. Choose an element by index.

Comment: Or just add the sizes of `L1.Size + L2.Size` (gives N), pick a random number between 0-N-1 (call it K), if `K < L1.Size`, pick it from L1. `If K >= L1`, pick `K - L1.Size` from `L2`. No need to create a new array since that would be very costly.

Comment: @kha No need to discuss optimizations here, I think. If it had been a real task, it would have been solved different in the first place.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering!  I really tried but sincerely didnt get the result. That´s ok because im getting used to this. I made a mistake as well and i update the code fully and i think that now it is understandable. Sorry for that and thanks for the attention @kha and Denis

Answer (score 0):

The first bug I'm seeing in your code is that `listOne()` returns object `listTwo` when called, which doesn't exist. It probably shouldn't even compile, unless something funky is going on with global scope variables.

The following code should do what you want by merging the two lists into one and then returning a random object from them.

```
public Object randomFromList(List<Object> listOne, List<Object> listTwo){
    List<Object> bigList = new ArrayList<Object>(listOne.size() + listTwo.size());
    bigList.addAll(listOne);
    bigList.addAll(listTwo);
    return bigList.get(new Random().nextInt(bigList.size()));
}
```

For optimization, if you call this a lot, I would save the `Random()` object outside of the method to avoid instantiating it every time you make the call.

Comment: Hey thanks for that! but im not getting it right i think. I updated the question/code with the action im trying to perform (sorry not posting it before). Im trying to call it from the MainActivity on performing a buttonclick, then ill shuffle it using ListMixer.

Comment: OK, it seems like what you want when you click the button is for the List itself to be mixed? Not to just return a random element from the list, but to reorder the list in a random way?
What do you expect to happen when you click the button? Is a view updated anywhere, or debug printed to logcat?

Comment: Yes, for example, i have a list with 5 people, other list with 5 people, other with 10, other with 20. All of these people has different ages. Then want to mix all of these lists and return two people with same age ex. 35 and 35 (or a similar age ex. 29 and 30, 35 and 37).
did you understand more or less?